# Why is an int variable valued `0xffffffff >> 1` != 0x7fffffff, unlike for a literal constant?

Tags: c, types, literals

```c
  int c = 0xffffffff;
  printf("%x\n", (c) == (0xffffffff));
  printf("%x\n", (c >> 1) == (0xffffffff >> 1));
```

The first output is `1` but the second output is `0`.
And `c >> 1` outputs `0xffffffff`. But why?

Comment: Try to print `c >> 1`  and `0xffffffff >> 1`.

Comment: `int` and `unsigned int`. I agree: try to print the values to inspect this better.

Comment: `c >> 1` is `0xffffffff`, `0xffffffff >> 1` is `0x7ffffffff`.

Comment: @HanwGeek then you should ask _that_

Comment: @HanwGeek wouldn't you agree they are not equal?

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I say that in the question. But I still don't know why it should be `0xffffffff`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `0xffffffff` on your platform is a value of type `unsigned int`.
Therefore `0xffffffff >> 1` equals `0xffffffffU >> 1` which is `0x7fffffffU`.

When you assign a value of type `unsigned int` to a variable of type `int` the value is *converted* to the target type. `0xffffffff` i.e. 4294967295 is outside the range of a 32-bit **signed integer**, so naturally it cannot be stored as is. But because your computer uses two's complement system, the **bits** will remain the same, i.e. all bits will be set, but the value is interpreted as **-1** instead of **4294967295**.

The behaviour of right shift on **negative** integers is **implementation-defined** in the C standard. [GCC defines](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html) it as arithmetic right shift, i.e. using sign extension. So the *bit representation* `ffffffff` shifted right by 1 will result in `ffffffff` bit representation; which as signed int signifies value `-1`.

Finally when you compare an `int` against an `unsigned int` using the `==` operator, the operands will undergo "usual arithmetic conversions" - the `int` -1  will be converted to an `unsigned int` - which on two's complement systems *retains* the bit pattern i.e. `ffffffff`, but now the value will be interpreted as 4294967295 instead of -1. But that value compares unequal to 0x7fffffff (2147483647), which has value

---

What is **more** confusing is that the **value of `c` does not equal the `0xffffffff` even though the equality operator returns true**! The value of `c` will be -1, and the value of `0xffffffff` is `0xffffffffu` i.e. `4294967295` and clearly the difference between `-1` and `4294967295` is 4294967296! But it is exactly because of the `signed/unsigned` comparison that **different** values can compare to equal - and for example GCC **will** warn about this with `-Wextra`:

```
warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
    5 |   printf("%x\n", (c) == (0xffffffff));
      |                      ^~
[venv][vrcappsdev][master✗]
```

To see that the values indeed are distinct, you need to cast both sides to a type that is large enough to contain both of them - `long long int` is a portable one:

```
printf("%d\n", (long long int)c == (long long int)0xffffffff);
```

will not print 1.

Comment: *`long long int` is a portable one* When did MSVC implement `long long int`?  I suspect there's a good chance there are still people using a version of MSVC that doesn't implement `long long int` as a standard type.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ah I was notified of this out-of-band 3 hours ago but forgot to fix :D

Answer (score 8):

The integer constant `0xffffffff` has the type `unsigned int`.  So when you perform a right shift on this value, bits with value 0 are shifted in from the left.

In contrast, `c` is an `int` and contains a negative value.  Performing a right shift on a negative value is implementation-defined, although most implementations will preserve the sign by shifting in bits with value 1 from the left.

---

As to why this prints 1 when comparing a positive and a negative value:

```
printf("%x\n", (c) == (0xffffffff));
```

It has to do with **integer conversions**.

When 0xffffffff (which is unsigned) is assigned to `c`, it undergoes an implementation-defined conversion because the value is out of range.  On a two's complement system, this will typically mean that the representation will be applied directly to the destination.  So now `c` has the value -1 with the representation 0xffffffff.

Now for the comparison.  The constant `0xffffffff` is unsigned and has the value 2<sup>32</sup>-1.  When comparing a signed value with an unsigned value of the same size, the signed value is converted to unsigned.  This happens (according to the standard) by adding the maximum value of an `unsigned int` + 1 to the signed value to put it in range.  So the signed value -1 is converted to the unsigned value 2<sup>32</sup>-1.  This is the same value as 0xffffffff so the comparison is true.